# Scheme: Lambda Recursion: Combining two lists elements by elements

Tags: scheme

I just started learning Scheme and we got to anonymous functions. We are learning how to recurse lambda and I understand recursing single variable functions like finding factorial, but how will I do it for a function like the one below?

```
    (define (two-list list1 list2)
      (cond
        [(empty? list1) empty]
        [else (cons (string-append (first list1)(first list2))
                     (two-list (rest list1)(rest list2)))]))
```

Here, I am trying to take two lists of string and combine them elements by elements.

Comment: My bad, I didn't make myself clear enough. What we have to do is convert that code into one that uses lambda. We are learning about lambda recursion.

Comment: The above is _already_ using `lambda`, it's just that it's hidden behind a bit of syntactic sugar. I updated my answer with equivalent code to reflect this

Comment: Oh, I see it now thank you! Just out of curiosity, would it be possible to make the entire thing lambda, like make this function work without defining anything.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to implement recursion using only anonymous functions (`lambda`s). Check out the [Y-Combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator)

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a read. If it isn't too much work mind doing it to the function I have so I can have a reference? :)

Comment: OK, I'll do it, but in about an hour or two, I'm going home right now :P

Comment: Okay thank you very much! I'll be playing around with Y-combinator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a recursive function that receives two lists as arguments is no different from implementing a single-argument function: just process each element in turn and advance over both lists, according to the rules of the problem you want to solve. In fact, there isn't anything wrong with the code you posted (assuming both lists have the same length). Here's the result of executing it:

```
(two-list '("1" "2" "3") '("4" "5" "6"))
=> '("14" "25" "36")
```

Perhaps some comments will make it clear:

```
(define two-list        ; code 100% equivalent to the one in the question
  (lambda (list1 list2) ; here lambda is explicit, it was implicit before
    (cond
      [(empty? list1) ; if one list is finished then
       empty]         ; end recursion and return the empty list
      [else           ; otherwise
       (cons (string-append  ; cons the result of performing an operation
              (first list1)  ; over the first list's first element and
              (first list2)) ; the second list's first element
             (two-list       ; finally, advance the recursion
              (rest list1)   ; over the first list and
              (rest list2)))]))) ; over the second list too
```

**UPDATE**

As a proof of concept of what was mentioned in the comments, here's how to implement the same procedure using the [Y-Combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator). In this way, we don't need to `define` anything:

```
(((λ (X) ; Y-Combinator
    ((λ (proc)
       (proc proc))
     (λ (proc)
       (X (λ (arg1 arg2)
            ((proc proc) arg1 arg2))))))
  (λ (two-list) ; `two-list` procedure it's just a parameter
    (λ (list1 list2)
      (cond
        [(empty? list1) empty]
        [else (cons (string-append (first list1) (first list2))
                    (two-list (rest list1) (rest list2)))]))))
 '("1" "2" "3") '("4" "5" "6")) ; here we pass the arguments

=> '("14" "25" "36")
```